# AngularJS repeat sample doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, controller, repeat

Recently I saw the below ng-repeat sample code.  It looks much simple than that in the official angularjs web site.  However it doesn't work in my local environment.
There's no error messages in the console.  The repeat doesn't show anything.  I was totally confused.  What's wrong with the ng-repeat below?

http://jsfiddle.net/331kfnk5/

```
<div ng-app>
  <ul class="example-animate-container">
    <li ng-controller="orderprovider" class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="i in items">
        {{i.id}} , {{i.total}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: check, do you properly included JS file in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the controller out of ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-app>
  <ul class="example-animate-container" ng-controller="orderprovider">
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="i in items">
        {{i.id}} , {{i.total}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

ng-repeat creates copies of the DOM element and in the code above it creates multiple instances of the `orderprovider` controller.
Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZjyEWGhdtoPx9Mis10jy?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/331kfnk5/4/

**html**

```
<body ng-app="app">        
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <ul class="example-animate-container">
            <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="i in items">
                {{ i.id }} , {{ i.total }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        { id: 'x10242458', total: 100, actual: 80 },
        { id: 'x10242408', total: 10, actual: 8 },
        { id: 'x10242308', total: 101, actual: 81 }
    ];
});
```

You were missing a few key things, like loading the Angular app, you were also including the controller on a repeatable element, which I have never tried before, but I am guessing will cause **bad** things to happen.

From there it was just a case of adding a proper Controller closure and loading the Angular framework at the correct time.